# How to only output the days (without hours, minutes, and seconds) while using time delta?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a function:

```
def diffDate(YYYY,MM,DD):
    tgl = date(YYYY,MM,DD)
    skrg = datetime.date(datetime.now())
    if tgl <= skrg:
        diffDate = skrg - tgl
    elif tgl >= skrg:
        diffDate = tgl - skrg
    return diffDate
```

The output will be "x days, 0:00:00". How to only output the days without the hours, minutes, and seconds? And can I multiple the day difference with integer without taking the 'days' ?
*Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Try `diffDate.days`.

Comment: That worked! 
I think I have tried that before and didn't work, but when I check it, I used 'diffDate(YYYY, MM, DD).day' instead of 'diffDate(YYYY, MM, DD).days' 

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple steps in one:

```
datetime import date

def absoluteDaysToNow(yyyy, mm, dd):
  delta = date.today() - date(yyyy, mm, dd)
  return abs( delta.days )
```

See: python docs, [built-in function abs()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs), [date example: days difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-date)